# What does <T> mean here?

Tags: java

This problem is from Question 3.5 in Cracking the Coding Interview 5th Edition. The solutions was like this:

```
public class MyQueue<T> {
Stack<T> stackNewest, stackOldest;
......
}
```

So what does two < T > here mean? I searched a lot of pages and didn't get answer. Thanks.

Comment: Search for `generics`.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/simple.html

Comment: **To the downvoters:** For a beginner in Java, it might be difficult to figure out the correct terminology to search for generics. While a fairly basic question, I think this question does show some research effort (searched several pages in their book for the solution), the question is clear, and it may be useful for other beginners. If you think the question should be closed then consider flagging it instead of downvoting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the parametrization. It makes use of Java Generics to produce parametrized Classes. In your case, the class `MyQueue<T>` has parametrization 'T' and inside the class the `Stack<T>` data structure too has been parametrized with 'T'.
If you are not aware of Generics, I would suggest [this article](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/) given in the documentation.